# Using curl, how do I download a .diff file from a private repository on github

Tags: curl, github

I have a private repo on github, belonging to an org. For a given pull request, there's a url to a diff file like this:

```
https://github.com/<ORG>/<REPO>/pull/<PR_NUMBER>.diff
```

But the repo is private, so how can I download this file with curl? I generated a "personal access token", but am a bit lost as to how to use it.

I tried this:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: token <TOKEN>' -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw' -O -L "https://github.com/<ORG>/<REPO>/pull/<PR_NUMBER>.diff"
```

But all that sent back was "Not Found".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the pull request url from api.github.com with different accept content type. e.g.

```
curl -H 'Authorization: token mytoken' -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.diff" https://api.github.com/repos/orgname/repo/pulls/1234
```

Notice: Please remove ".diff" suffix from the url.

Comment: Works splendidly!

Comment: No longer works.

Answer (score 0):

The [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#via-oauth-tokens) returns a 404 for all unauthorized requests -- mostly to hide the existence/non-existence of user/org data at the requested URL. So the 404 you are getting back *may* actually be a 401.

When sending a request to the GH api via curl, you should use the `u` option to send your token rather than the `Authorization` header, resulting in the following request:

`curl -u <USERNAME>:<TOKEN> \
 -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.raw' -O -L \ 
 "https://github.com/<ORG>/<REPO>/pull/<PR_NUMBER>.diff"`

Comment: I still get a Not Found either with un/pw or un/token combination.

Comment: @polytopia did you find a solution? I'm always getting a 404 even sending the proper auth headers

Comment: i get redirect in both cases

Answer (score 0):

Works as of 2022. Note that the URL is the same between this and the previously-accepted answer, but the authentication method needs to change:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3.diff" https://<personal access token>:x-oauth-basic@api.github.com/repos/<org>/<repo>/pulls/<pull request>
```

Also works with the normal cURL `-u` parameter.

See: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#get-a-pull-request